# LinkedIn API - Not enough permissions - rest/posts

Tags: linkedin-api

We detected issue when trying to reach this endpoint:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialMetadata?ids=List(‘<encoded ids>’)
```

and error message is:

```
“Not enough permissions to access: artnerApiSocialMetadata.BATCH_GET.20231101”
{status: 403, serviceErrorCode: 100, code: "ACCESS_DENIED",…}
    code: "ACCESS_DENIED"
    message: "Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiSocialMetadata.BATCH_GET.20231101"
    serviceErrorCode: 100
    status: 403
```

It was working till yesterday (14.12.2023 with “old” token, but today with new generated token it is not working at all).

We still have access to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<companyId>&q=author&count=<numberOfPosts>
```

We created new token with the same scopes like at the old token – `(r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, r_organization_social, w_member_social)` but without success.

Then we created newer one with the all privileges which the user has `(r_1st_connections_size, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, r_organization_admin, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social)` also without success.

Access token details

- Created on:
- less than 10 seconds ago (1702635745 UTC)
- Last authorized:
- less than 10 seconds ago (1702635745 UTC)
- Expires:
- in 2 months (1707819749 UTC)
- Authentication type:
- 3-legged
- Permissions:
- r_1st_connections_size, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, r_organization_admin, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social
- Status:
- OAuth token is active

In documentation (Social Metadata API - LinkedIn | Microsoft Learn) I’ve found that maybe there was changed the name of the scope, but we don’t see that name of permission: (screen below):

[image]

For example in developer program I see still “old permission name” (screen below):

[image]

We have tried to open the support request for LinkedIn, but they told us:

> I'm sorry for the trouble this has caused. At this time we do not have a support team that directly supports the API features on LinkedIn.
>
> You're welcome to post the question to our Stack Overflow where the community can look to help resolve any technical issues you may be facing with the identity vetting issue you're seeing - https://developer.linkedin.com/support/stackoverflow
>
> ProdCaseResponse <caseresponse@linkedin.com>

Answer (score 0):

You may have run into [a nasty little caching bug in the LinkedIn API auth implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847103/linkedin-api-access-denied-not-enough-permissions-to-access).

After you change which permissions you request, you need to wait at least 5 minutes before testing out the new code. Otherwise, your new access token will behave as if it has the permissions of the old access token.

This bug bit me so bad that I [created an app](https://github.com/twobitfool/linkedin-auth-bug/) to prove it -- which was also helpful when I reported the issue to LinkedIn a while back. No news on when (or if) they will ever fix it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. We have tried, but without success. We have also create the new app and requested again the access rights, but  the issue is the same.